# NuSoap not sending parameters when wsdl

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am using a NuSoap Client for a requisition.

```
$client = new nusoap_client($this->endpoint, true);
$parameters = array("parameter1" => 1, "parameter2" => 2);
$client->call("SomeMethod", $parameters);`
```

When I set the `nusoap_client` second parameter to true (it means if is `wsdl` or not), then my requisition goes without ANY of my parameters sent in line 2, and then returns a validation error because there is no parameters sent.

When I set `nusoap_client` `wsdl` to `false`, then my parameters in line 2 are sent as expected but return `Internal server error` because `wsdl` should be `true`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can gather error information like this:

```
$client->call("SomeMethod", $parameters);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Error</h2>' . $err;
    exit();
}
else 
{ 
    echo $result; 
}
```

That would be my first step.

Comment: The error when I set in nusoap_client, wsdl = true is an error of the endpoint validation saying that the parameters is missing. Not relevant to post the error here. The point is when set wsdl to TRUE, the requisition is going WITHOUT my parameters. And when set wsdl to FALSE, then my parameters goes as expected but the endpoint return an error because it is an wsdl.

Comment: What is the server/service?  Can you share that?

Do you have documentation on what it expects?

Comment: Can you post the full request and response from after the call?

// Display the request and response

echo '<h2>Request</h2>';

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';

echo '<h2>Response</h2>';

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but I had now the same problem. The solution was that the passed-in parameter array needs to have an exactly matched key to the field name used in the WSDL.

```
$result = $client->call('wsdlOperation', array('NameOfParamInRequest' => $param));
```

"NameOfParamInRequest" was the name of the parameter in the associated request for the WSDL operation named "wsdlOperation"